# show/hide fields based on checkbox selection in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, list-form

I am creating a SharePoint form and I have a few check-boxes and based on if the checkbox is checked or not an additional column appears.

But I can't get to hide that additional column if then box is not checked, can anyone help?

Comment: How are you getting the additional column to show?  Can you post an example of your code?

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using to your question?

Comment: Thank you for this- nearly what I need;
please advise how to display <<option> if box A or Box B is checked?
only when A or B is uncked does the option field disappear
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sample demo to show/hide column(row) based on checkbox click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //MultiChoice Field static name
        $('input', 'table[id^="MultiChoice"]').each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    //Option  field title
                    $('nobr:contains("Option")').closest('tr').hide();
                } else {
                    $('nobr:contains("Option")').closest('tr').show();
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

[image]